# logcheck sending smbd: pam_unix(samba:session): session opened/closed messages

Tags: debian, samba, logcheck

Fresh Debian install. Samba standalone server. logcheck installed.

Getting lots of these messages via emails, how to suppress any idea?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
Jan  6 02:04:05 debian smbd: pam_unix(samba:session): session opened for user xxx by (uid=0)
Jan  6 02:25:52 debian smbd: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user xxx
```

Comment: Tried editing /etc/pam.d/samba to this to no avail...
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet
[/code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add regular expressions e.g. in the file `/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/samba`

```
^\w{3} [ :[:digit:]]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ smbd: pam_unix\(samba:session\): session opened for user [[:alnum:]]+ by \(uid=[[:digit:]]+\)$
^\w{3} [ :[:digit:]]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ smbd: pam_unix\(samba:session\): session closed for user [[:alnum:]]+$
```

Comment: BTW, what if I want to suppress these entries completely? is editing /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive right?